# extJS 4 Component Layout

Tags: layout, extjs4

I was wondering what would be the best way of achieving a layout like this in extJS:

[image: extJS Layout]

I have 4 different components that I would like to place in each respective box but am having trouble figuring out exactly how I can do it.

Here is a snippet of some code I have been working on:

```
Ext.define('/../../../chefCreateAndPinRolesLayoutContainer', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',

    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    items: [{
            flex: 1,
            items: [
                Ext.create('/../../../chefRequiredCookbooksGridPanel'),
                Ext.create('/../../../chefRoleSetupFormPanel')
            ]
    }, {
            flex: 1,
            items: [
                Ext.create('/../../../chefOptionalCookbooksGridPanel'),
                Ext.create('/../../../chefAttributeGridContainer')
            ]
    }]
});
```

Here is what my current layout comes out to:

[image: Current Layout]

I'd like for it to fill the whole Tab Panel and have equal widths and heights per section.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below snippet, where internal container items(A, B, C, D) can be replaced with your custom items.

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
         Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
             layout: 'fit',
             items: [{
                 xtype: 'container',
                 layout: {
                     type: 'hbox',
                     align: 'stretch'
                 },
                 items: [{
                     xtype: 'container',
                     flex: 1,
                     layout: {
                         type: 'vbox',
                         align: 'stretch'
                     },
                     border: 1,
                     items: [
                         {
                             xtype: 'container',
                             html: 'Cell A content',
                             flex: 1
                         },{
                             xtype: 'container',
                             html: 'Cell B content',
                             flex: 1
                         }
                     ]
                 }, {
                         xtype: 'container',
                         flex: 1,
                         layout: {
                             type: 'vbox',
                             align: 'stretch'
                         },
                         items: [
                         {
                             xtype: 'container',
                             html: 'Cell C content',
                             flex: 1
                         },{
                             xtype: 'container',
                             html: 'Cell D content',
                             flex: 1
                         }
                        ]
                 }]
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: You sir, are awesome!